# Why the year of the gods are taken as divine years for yuga calculations?

Tags: gods, yuga, kali-yuga

By taking the year of gods i.e 360 earth years we get a huge time frame of 360*1200 = 432000 years for Kaliyuga. Are we not making God a material being by assigning such numbers which could also mean that Gods are also subject to birth and death cycle. God is supposed to be omnipresent. kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: Well one day of god is taken as 4 years of human life, so one year of god equals 360 times 4 equalling 1080 years of human life.

Comment: 4 years of man = 1 day of God? What God are you speaking about? There are complex calculations about this matter.

Comment: 365*(1/4) human days = 1 Deva Ahoratra (1 day + 1 night).


360 Deva Ahoratras = 1 Deva Vatsara.


12,000 Deva Vatsaras = 1 Chaturyuga ** (our reference point)
(3,000 Deva Vatsaras = 1 Yuga).


71 Chaturyugas = 1 Manvantara.


14 Manvantaras = 1 Kalpa.


2 Kalpas = 1 Day of Brahma + 1 Night of Brahma.


360 Days of Brahma = 1 Brahma Varsha.


Brahma's life span is 100 Brahma Varshas

Answer (score 2):

By years of the Gods, they mean Devas. Deva, Nara and Asura are the 3 broad classes of beings. Devas are celestials. Everybody is a manifestation of GOD, but Devas are the ones whose consciousness levels are prevalent in the higher Lokas and are closer to illumination and purity, whereas humans (nara) live in the Bhur Loka where we are subject to both illumination and ignorance, hence we suffer as well as receive pleasure. Asuras on the other hand, along with Nagas, live in the Talas, which are situated below Bhur Loka.

> My dear son Nārada, know from me that there are seven lower planetary
>   systems out of the total  fourteen. The first planetary system, known
>   as Atala, is situated on the waist; the second, Vitala, is situated on
>   the thighs; the third, Sutala, on the knees; the fourth, Talātala, on
>   the shanks; the fifth, Mahātala, on the ankles; the sixth, Rasātala,
>   on the upper portion of the feet; and the seventh, Pātāla, on the
>   soles of the feet. Thus the virāṭ form of the Lord is full of all
>   planetary systems.
>
> (Srimad Bhagavatam 2:5:40-41)

Unfortunately I could not find the citation for the Lokas.

As per the macrocosmic level, Devas exist externally as a conscious force/vibration/energy in the universe, who can be invoked by mantras. Its these Devas whose time is taken into account while calculating divine years.

Comment: Thanks for the details. If the divine is in everything and in every size and time scale  why allocate such large numbers. Should not these numbers be just used as a scale up factor for each time unit?

Comment: The original text in surya siddhant uses the word divya years for describing the time scale of yugas.

Comment: The large allocation of numbers, according to my understanding, is just because of the predominance of "kaala" over every loka in the material realm. Remember that the spiritual realm of Vaikuntha and above is not under the influence of Kaala, hence is eternal. But the material realm is subject to destruction and reconstruction. According to general relativity, time dilation is a concept which was also elaborated in a story where Raivata goes to Brahmalok and after a few minutes, gets to know that an entire generation has passed on Bhurloka.

Comment: So the large quantity of time which has passed in the human realm, accounts for the little time which has passed in Brahmalok. Its only for measuring the time differences between different lokas. 

Remember, time dilation is only possible in lokas which are ascending increasingly according to gravitational pull. This is where I as a metaphysicist try to combine science with spirituality. The highest loka is a place of very high gravity, hence time moves faster in those lokas. The higher the gravitational potential (the farther the clock is from the source of gravity), the faster time passes

Comment: So that means we cannot practically say that kaliyuga will last 432000 earth years. Hope this is what you mean.

Comment: Kaliyuga might or might not. I cannot say it for sure. But I personally believe so. And Gods do die....rather....merge into their source at the end of the universe, and resurface again at the start of another creation.

Comment: "Bhishma said, 'O mighty-armed one, the peace and prosperity of
subjects,[425] sufficiency and seasonableness of rain, disease, death and
other fears, are all dependent on the king.[426] I have no doubt also in
this. O bull of Bharata's race, that Krita, Treta, Dwapara, and Kali, as
regards their setting in, are all dependent on the king's conduct.

Comment: The above is answered  to Yudhisthira by Bheeshma in Mahabharata. That is why came to believe that age is a state of mind. However sage Vyasa also talks of 432000 year kaliyug.

Comment: Maybe it is so that when ignorance reaches its peak, Kalki will descend, irrespective of the time limit

Comment: I agree 100% on that one. Thanks for all the insight.

Comment: No no, I should thank you too for sharing your insights with me. We are all here to learn isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It's referring to Devas not to Lord Hari.  The time period for Lord Bramha is also Different. Here it's specifically referring to the Time period of Devas like Indra, Varuna etc of Svarga etc, they change after each Manvantar.

These dates are not subject to Lord Sri Hari he is eternal nor to his Expansion Sri Sada Shiv. They both along with their Associates are Beyong material time and space.